# ruby/rails: How to access instances inside a class method called on an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

For reasons too long to list here, I can't use a typical `has_many/belongs_to` configuration.  I need to access all the instances within an association inside of a class method.  I have the following

```
class Impression
    def self.tags
        Tag.where(id: self.map(&:tag_id))
    end
end
```

The idea is so that I can write something like this and have it return all of the tags for the given impression:

```
i = Impression.last(50)
puts "self is #{self.inspect}"
i.tags
```

The problem is that when I do this I get:

```
self is Impression(id: integer, impressionable_type: string, ......
NoMethodError (undefined method `map' for #<Class:0x00007ff5562cadc8>)
```

How Do I access the instances inside of the relation returned by `i = Impression.last(50)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left aside talking if you should, you can do:

```rb
class Impression
  def self.tags
    Tag.where(id: self.all.select(:tag_id))
  end
end
```

rails will do its magic when you call it on a relation.

if `tag_id` is not a db field - replace `select` with `to_a.map(&:tag_id)`

Comment: Thanks! All I had to do was add `all` to my code.  I was running map on the class instead of all the classes instances.

Comment: @Philip7899 trick here is that most probably you do not need to load the instances at all

Comment: But `pluck` will pull all the `tag_id`s out of the database as an array and then you send them all back. You'd be better off with `Tag.where(id: all.select(:tag_id))` so that AR would use a subquery (`where id in (select tag_id from ..))` rather than an inlined list (`where id in (1, 2, ..)`).